# Как соединить две окружности прямой

Tags: c#, графика

Имеются две окружности одного радиуса R с центрами в точках x1, y1; x2, y2, с произвольным расположением.

Вопрос: как провести прямую, которая соединяла бы эти окружности, но при этом не пересекала их? 
Вариант с перерисовыванием окружностей поверх прямой не годится.
Прямую рисую вот так:

```
Brush red = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
Pen redPen = new Pen(red, 2);         
gr.DrawLine(redPen, x1, y1, x2, y2);
```

[image: как нужно]
[image: что сейчас есть]

Comment: Общие касательные то бишь?

Comment: рисовать прямую не от центров окружностей, а от точек на самой окружности

Comment: @Grundy я не знаю как найти эти искомые точки

Comment: Ну а чуток подумать, про вычитание из координат центров окружностей их радиусов помноженных на sin и сos. Насколько я понимаю Вы тему подобных треугольников в школе не проходили? И вот такая публика потом идет работать программистом.

Comment: Довольно банальная векторная алгебра: взять вектор из центра в центр и привести его умножением на число к длине, равной радиусу. Никаких синусов-косинусов.

Comment: @D-side, я не понял что ты сказал :-D Напиши ответ с примером

Comment: @Grundy http://www.gamedev.ru/code/terms/Normalization -- нормализовать и домножить на радиус окружности.

Comment: @D-side , боюсь, что клиент не знает, что такое вектор

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов и теперь он хотя бы знает, куда ему расти!

Comment: @D-side и чего будет то? получите вектор длины R вместо (L-2R), где L - расстояние между центрами.

Comment: @teran так получится одна точка из двух. Аналогично, но вычитанием из второго центра, получается вторая. Всё, победа.

Comment: @D-side, а координаты потом начала конца откуда брать? Что-то мне кажется ты куда-то не туда шагнул :)

Comment: @Grundy он координаты конца и начала и считает (:

Comment: @teran, я что-то не понял как вычитанием из вектора получить точку

Comment: Почему вариант с перерисовыванием круга поверх линий не годится, если не секрет?

Comment: @Vladimir Gamalian  я рисую прямую с наконечником, в таком случае необходимо касаться самой окружности

Answer (score 3):

У вас есть окружности с центрами в `O1 = (x1, y1)` и `O2 = (x2, y2)`, радиуса `r`.

Заведём вектор `C`, указывающий из центра первой окружности в центр второй: классическое "конечные минус начальные": `C = O2 - O1 = (x2 - x1, y2 - y1)`.

Но это смещение, лишённое "базовой точки". Для чего оно? Для того, чтобы вычислить смещение каждого из двух концов искомого отрезка относительно центров окружностей. Если присмотреться, видно, что смещения одинаковы, просто выполнены в прямо противоположные стороны. И направлены они параллельно (коллинеарно, в векторных терминах) `C`.

У нас есть правильно направленный вектор, но неправильной длины. Но длину можно исправить, умножив вектор на число `m = r / length(C)`.

Получится вектор `S = C * m = (C.x * m, C.y * m)`.
`O1 + S` это одна точка отрезка, `O2 - S` другая.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добавь картинки :-)

Comment: я бы еще как-то обозначил начало координат на картинке, чтобы было понятно почему O1 и O2 начинаются в одной точке, и как точка может быть вектором. Как показала практика это далеко не всем очевидно

Comment: @rdorn стало лучше?

Comment: классно. а плюсиком я давно отметился =)

Comment: @rdorn меня больше беспокоит понятность ответа, чем плюсики, но спасибо :)

Comment: при минимальном представлении о векторах, все понятно, без оного сложнее, но картинка довольно хорошо поясняет. Приводить картинки как происходит сумма и разность векторов не вижу смысла, разве что ссылки на ту же вики оставить.

Answer (score 2):

Я разобрался и нашел более простое решение:

```
 double theta = Math.Atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1);
 x1 = x1 + r * cos(theta)
 y1 = y1 + r * sin(theta)
```

Вторая координата (x2, y2) находится аналогично, только радиус вычитается

Comment: отлично, что смогли разобраться. Только вот более "простое" решение использует тригонометрические функции, вычисление которых существенно сложнее и дает бОльшую погрешность, чем векторное решение. Погрешностью можно пренебречь, т.к. на выходе координаты пикселя, а они целые. А вот сложность вычисления тригонометрии может не лучшим образом сказаться на производительности, если эти вычисления не разовые.

Comment: @rdorn Спасибо, буду иметь в виду.

Answer (score 0):

Алгоритм вычисления крайних точек следующий:

```
int x1 = 0, y1 = 0, r1 = 1, x2 = 3, y2 = 4, r2 = 1;
// получаем единичный вектор направленный от центра первой окружности ко второй
Vector2 norm = Vector2.Normalize(new Vector2(x2-x1, y2-y1));
// удлиняем его на радиусы окружностей
Vector2 v1 = Vector2.Multiply(r1, norm);
// для конца линии умножаем на отрицательный скаляр - получаем вектор в обратном направлении
Vector2 v2 = Vector2.Multiply(-r2, norm);
// Искомые точки получаем простым суммированием:
Console.WriteLine("(" + (x1+v1.X) +", "+ (y1+v1.Y)+") - (" + (x2+v2.X) +", "+ (y2+v2.Y)+")");
```